# Would using Switch command fix the error in T-SQL code

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm getting the following error in the following case statement:

> Error in list of function arguments: 'THEN' not recognized.
> Error in list of function arguments: ',' not recognized.
> Unable to parse query text.

I also tried using `Switch` which had an error = not recognized

Thank you for your suggestions!

```
Case
    When ([gdklinkID] = 1 then [stuListName]
    When [gdklinkID] = 2 then [tblmissionsite].[msnname]
    When [gdklinkID] = 4 then [spname]
    When [gdklinkid] = 6 then 'Best Use'
    When [gdklinkid] = 7 then [gdaname]
    When [gdklinkid] = 12, then 'Pass Thru'
    Else 'oops'
End AS CatDetail,
Case
    When [gdklinkID] = 1 then 'Contrib-StuFam'
    When [gdklinkid] < 5 then 'Contributions-Designated'
    When [gdklinkid] = 5 then 'Grants'
    When [gdklinkid] = 6 then 'Contributions-Undesignated'
    When [gdklinkid] = 7 and [gdaid] = 84 then 'Dividends'
    When [gdklinkid] = 7 and [gdaid] = 146 then 'Chk'
    When [gdklinkid] = 7 and [gdaid] = 147 then 'Svgs'
    When [gdklinkid] = 7 then  'Contributions-Undesignated'
    When [gdklinkid] = 12 then 'Pass Thru'
    Else 'oops'
End  AS CatDetail2
```

Comment: Several typos: very first `when` in your first `case` - remove that opening bracket `(`. Very last item of the first case - remove the comma `,` after the value `12`. And also: T-SQL doesn't have any `switch` command / function ..... that's just in C# or other programming languages...

Comment: A tip I use when I get issues with my queries: When you get errors that you don't know where they originated from, simplify your queries by starting with two rows and study them well. Build on them until you hit the issue again and that is where you study that particular row to find the issue. Hope this method helps you in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the open Bracket just after the first when

```
Case
    When [gdklinkID] = 1 then [stuListName]
    When [gdklinkID] = 2 then [tblmissionsite].[msnname]
    When [gdklinkID] = 4 then [spname]
    When [gdklinkid] = 6 then 'Best Use'
    When [gdklinkid] = 7 then [gdaname]
    When [gdklinkid] = 12, then 'Pass Thru'
    Else 'oops'
End AS CatDetail,

Case
    When [gdklinkID] = 1 then 'Contrib-StuFam'
    When [gdklinkid] < 5 then 'Contributions-Designated'--will this not satisfy the condition above? (When [gdklinkID] = 1 then 'Contrib-StuFam')
    When [gdklinkid] = 5 then 'Grants'
    When [gdklinkid] = 6 then 'Contributions-Undesignated'
    When [gdklinkid] = 7 and [gdaid] = 84 then 'Dividends'
    When [gdklinkid] = 7 and [gdaid] = 146 then 'Chk'
    When [gdklinkid] = 7 and [gdaid] = 147 then 'Svgs'
    When [gdklinkid] = 7 then  'Contributions-Undesignated'
    When [gdklinkid] = 12 then 'Pass Thru'
    Else 'oops'
End  AS CatDetail2
```